# Как программно создать задачу в планировщике Windows из под ограниченной учетки

Tags: windows, администрирование, планировщик-задач

Пытаюсь создать в командной строке из под ограниченной учетки:

```
schtasks /create /TN "calc" /TR "calc.exe" /sc ONLOGON /RU Domain\User
```

Пишет

> ОШИБКА: Отказано в доступе.

Но вот что интересно, если я под этим пользователем интерактивно открываю планировщик задач, задача без проблем создается интерактивно без всяких uac и т.д. Значит, должен быть способ сделать то же из консоли?

Comment: под каким "этим" пользователем? В параметре ``/ru`` указывается другой пользователь, не тот, под которым находится активный пользователь.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы пытаетесь запустить calc.exe (от имени пользователя Domain\User), при логине **любого** пользователя. Для этого нужны права администратора.

Вероятно вам нужно запускать программу только при логине пользователя Domain\User. Это невозможно сделать через обычные параметры командной строки (туда выведены не все опции). Воспользуйтесь XML - интерфейсом.

```
schtasks /create /XML calc.xml /TN calc
```

calc.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-16"?>
<Task version="1.2" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/windows/2004/02/mit/task">
  <Triggers>
    <LogonTrigger>
      <Enabled>true</Enabled>
      <UserId>Domain\User</UserId>
    </LogonTrigger>
  </Triggers>
  <Actions Context="Author">
    <Exec>
      <Command>calc.exe</Command>
    </Exec>
  </Actions>
</Task>
```

Чтобы составить такой xml, проще всего: создать задачу через графический интерфейс Task Scheduler-а, вызвать в нем "Export...", и убрать лишнее из полученного xml.